# Covariance non-zero mean AR(1)

Tags: self-study, arima, econometrics, covariance, stochastic-processes

Why when I compute the autocovariance function of a non-zero mean AR(1), 
X(t)-u=Φ(X(t-1)-u)+ε   the presence of the mean does not change my result and so the formula should be the same of a zero-mean AR(1)? I've tried to do that, but i obtain a extra-term (the yellow one), so there is something wrong!

[image]

Comment: Could you show where the "$Variance(X_{t-1})$ term comes from? I believe that in introducing it you have double-counted  a term equal to $-\phi u^2.$

Comment: @whuber The variance of X(t-1) is the result of the expectation of X(t-1) squared that I can write as variance

Comment: Haven't you assumed $E[X_{t-1}]=u$??  Unless $u=0,$ the expectation of $X_{t-1}^2$ is not its variance.

Comment: @whuber You re perfectly right. And so, what does  X(t-1) squared stand for?